# Select ListView items only by left-clicking them

Tags: java, javafx

When using a JavaFX ListView, if you **right-click** an item, the item is selected.

Is it possible to **only** select an item if you **left-click** it?

Comment: I thought you could stop right-click selecting by [setting an event filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/filters.htm#BCFDCCEJ) which consumed right mouse events.  But no - selections are independently triggered by a [ContextMenuEvent.CONTEXT_MENU_REQUESTED](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ContextMenuEvent.html#CONTEXT_MENU_REQUESTED) event, which you could filter, but that event only has `event.isKeyboardTrigger()`, so you can't filter on the mouse button used to initiate the event.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this question - perhaps a new custom ListView skin or behavior implementation.

Comment: I've just read your comment after I posted the code. Why wouldn't it work, i. e. what am I not seeing?

Comment: Maybe it is an environment specific thing.  I am using a touchpad on an OS X 10.9 Mac running Java 8u31.  A right-click is simulated on a touchpad by pressing two fingers on the touchpad simultaneously.  I do this and the filter will correctly detect the right click event in block it.  However, there is also a context menu event triggered and (for whatever reason) there is specific code in the JavaFX system to make that trigger a selection.

Comment: I'm such an idiot though, as the solution is incredibly simple - also filter and consume any `ContextMenuEvent.CONTEXT_MENU_REQUESTED` event on the list, not worrying about whatever triggered it.  I just tried adding code to do that to Roland's solution and it works fine.  I've edited Roland's solution to include this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just filter the MOUSE_PRESSED event, check if the secondary button is down, consume it and add your custom handling code if you need one.

A right-click can also trigger a `ContextMenuEvent.CONTEXT_MENU_REQUESTED` event on an OS X touchpad (and such events will, somewhat weirdly, trigger a selection) so also filter and consume these events.

This works for me:

```
public class ListViewSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("List View Sample");        

        ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();
        ObservableList<String> items =FXCollections.observableArrayList ( "Single", "Double", "Suite", "Family App");
        list.setItems(items);    

        // filter right mouse button
        list.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> 
        {
            if( e.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                e.consume();
            }

        });

        list.addEventFilter(ContextMenuEvent.CONTEXT_MENU_REQUESTED, Event::consume);

        // verify selection via logging
        list.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (ChangeListener<String>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println( "Item selected: " + observable + ", " + oldValue + ", " + newValue)
                );

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(list);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

may be this can help

-Controller

```
@FXML
ListView<String> listT=new ListView<String>();
@FXML
Label lbl=new Label();

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
     listT=new Listv(listT);

}
```

class extending listview

```
public class Listv extends ListView<String>{
ListView<String> llist=new ListView<String>();
int PrevIndex=0;

public Listv(ListView<String> l) {
    this.llist=l;
    llist.getItems().add("A");
    llist.getItems().add("A");
    llist.getItems().add("A");
    llist.getItems().add("A");
    this.llist.setOnMouseClicked(listclicked);
    this.llist.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(indexChanged);
}

EventHandler<MouseEvent> listclicked=new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {       
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if( event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY)
        {               
            Platform.runLater(()->{
                llist.getSelectionModel().select(PrevIndex);
            });          
        }
    }
};

ChangeListener<Object> indexChanged=new  ChangeListener<Object>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Object> observable,Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        PrevIndex=Integer.parseInt(oldValue.toString());
    }
};
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is it first select new one than goes to previous